# Attempt to copy files from Windows 10 host to Ubuntu VM (Hyper-V) gives error

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to copy files from Windows 10 host to Ubuntu VM (Hyper-V) using this command:

```
Copy-VMFile "UbuntuVM" -SourcePath C:\Users\file.pcap -DestinationPath "~/opt/..../file.pcap" -CreateFullPath -FileSource Host
```

The destination path is my Ubuntu location, however it does not feel right to map it this way.

When executing the command in powershell it give the following:

```
Copy-VMFile : Failed to initiate copying files to the guest. Failed to copy the source file to 
the destination
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-VMFile], VirtualizationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.CopyVMFile
```

The guest options are enabled.

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: Are you sure your given path exists (`opt` inside your home directory)? Additionally, `~` is relative to a user. How do you assert, that you are doing it for your desired user? Try to copy to an absolute path first, to narrow down the problem.

Comment: The location was incorrect, that is true. Thank you